# How to schedule a toast notification and set the tag in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, toast

I'm creating a toast notification using the `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications` NuGet and I can schedule notifications like this:

```
new ToastContentBuilder()
    .AddText("Hello world!")
    .SetToastDuration(ToastDuration.Long)
    .Schedule(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(15));
```

However, I can't see how I can add a tag to this new toast. This is how I would normally do it:

```
.Show(toast => {
    toast.Tag = "540";
});
```

`.Show` is a lambda expression that allows me to set the tag and show the toast at the same type, as described in the Microsoft example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=uwp#provide-a-primary-key-for-your-toast). This isn't suitable for my purposes because I want to schedule it - not show it immediately. I don't see a way I can set the tag *and* schedule it since `.Schedule` is not a lambda expression.

Is there any other way I can pull this off?

Comment: Any updates about this? Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The [ToastContentBuilder Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.notifications.toastcontentbuilder?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0) has a [Schedule(DateTimeOffset, CustomizeScheduledToast) method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.notifications.toastcontentbuilder.schedule?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-7.0#Microsoft_Toolkit_Uwp_Notifications_ToastContentBuilder_Schedule_System_DateTimeOffset_Microsoft_Toolkit_Uwp_Notifications_CustomizeScheduledToast_). In this method, you could add your toast when tryng to schedule it.

Please try the following code here:

```
new ToastContentBuilder()
.AddArgument("action", "viewItemsDueToday")
.AddText("ASTR 170B1")
.AddText("You have 3 items due today!");
.Schedule(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5), toast =>
{
    toast.Tag = "18365";
    toast.Group = "ASTR 170B1";
});
```

You could refer to this document for more information-- [Provide a primary key for your toast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/scheduled-toast#provide-a-primary-key-for-your-toast).